# Should I really not use px over dp in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

There are a lot of questions on this on here, but none that answer my specific question. When I use `px`, eclipse tells me to avoid it. So I did. But when I use `dp`, the grid/borders I am making around my cells in `GridView` seems too fat. I want it much thinner. When using 1 `px` as opposed to 1`dp`, I get the desired result. I understand warning on avoiding it, but should I really avoid it in this case?

Comment: android suggest dp to keep compatibility across devices.

Comment: Does `px` not work on all devices?

Comment: That part I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should. "dp" will give pretty the same look on all devices, but pixels are not.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Long story short:

The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

Comment: I understand that, but is there a way to show similar results using `dp` and not `px` in my case? It doesn't look like `dp` supports .5

Comment: What is your device dpi? It doesn't support because 1dp is 1px on 160dpi. And line cannot be thinner than 1px.

Comment: I am not sure, its the Galaxy Nexus

Comment: (315/160)*1dp = 1.97px I don't think that 0.03 of the pixel will be without color, apparently it's gonna be 2px on GalaxyNexus

Answer (score 1):

px doesnt work on all devices i think it stopped working in android 2.2
I recommend sticking with dp.

Comment: Your welcome, please rate one of the answers or accept them, thanks